# Make: Can we have directories as a target in GNUmakefile

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I am working on GNUmake to create symlink to specific file by parsing whole directory which has a folder which needs to be linked.

Here is my makefile snippet.

```
TGT_LINK = /lan/test/workspace/build/tools
all_target: release_buid complete_test $(TGT_LINK)

$(TGT_LINK): 
     if [ ! -d $@ ]; then mkdir -p $@; fi
    cd $@; \
    tar_ln=`\ls -d synopsystcl* | sed 's/synopsys//'`; \
    sour_dir=`\ls -d synopsystcl*`;  \
    if ! [ -e $tar_ln ]; then   \
        ln -s $sour_dir $tar_ln; \
    fi
```

Directory : /lan/test/workspace/build/tools Contains following content in it

```
polaris.so link.a dynamic.so kbuild.so README.txt license.txt synopsystcl5.5 build.json
```

Here i am trying to create symlink with name `tcl5.5` pointing to `synopsystcl5.5` with my above target `$(TGT_LINK)` code.

```
tcl5.5 -> synopsystcl5.5
```

After successful completion of two targets : `release_buid complete_test` , build is not proceeding to go for next target `$(TGT_LINK)` to create symlink. Could you please help whats wrong in code?

Comment: Does `/lan/test/workspace/build/tools` already exist?

Comment: Hi, It will be created while running build. Targets which ran before $(TGT_LINK) will create that directory.

Comment: If `$(TGT_LINK)` already exists and has no dependencies then why do you expect `make` to run the commands to create/update it?

Comment: Once after creation of that directory, i want to do some manipulation in that directory. I.e. i want to create one symlink in that directory as described in my description.

Comment: If you want something inside the directory to be built then you need to make that a target as well.  Alternatively you can declare the directory to be phony: `.PHONY: $(TGT_LINK)`.  That will force this recipe to run every time that target needs to be built regardless of whether or not it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would let `make` itself to check and recreate symlink as needed, i.e.:

```
TGT_LINK = /lan/test/workspace/build/tools
all_target: release_buid complete_test symlink

.PHONY: symlink
symlink: $(patsubst $(TGT_LINK)/tcl%, $(TGT_LINK)/synopsystcl%, $(wildcard $(TGT_LINK)/tcl*))

$(TGT_LINK)/synopsystcl%: $(TGT_LINK)/tcl%
        set -e; \
        cd $(@D); \
        rm -f $(@F); \
        ln -s $(<F) $(@F)
```

I would also consider reordering targets if there are dependencies indeed. One should never assume that dependency list is processed left to right; it will also lead to errors when parallel build (`-j`) is involved. If you have dependencies that something should happen before something else, it should be explicitly stated, e.g.:

```
all_target: symlink
symlink: complete_test
complete_test: release_buid
```